# NoSuchMethodError using Databricks Spark-Avro 3.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, avro, databricks, spark-avro

I have a spark master & worker running in Docker containers with spark 2.0.2 and hadoop 2.7. I'm trying to submit a job from pyspark from a different container (same network) by running

```
df = spark.read.json("/data/test.json")
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/data/test.avro")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.createDatumWriter(Lorg/apache/avro/Schema;)Lorg/apache/avro/io/DatumWriter;
```

It makes no difference if I try interactively or with spark-submit. These are my loaded packages in spark:

```
com.databricks#spark-avro_2.11;3.2.0 from central in [default]
com.thoughtworks.paranamer#paranamer;2.7 from central in [default]
org.apache.avro#avro;1.8.1 from central in [default]
org.apache.commons#commons-compress;1.8.1 from central in [default]
org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-core-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
org.codehaus.jackson#jackson-mapper-asl;1.9.13 from central in [default]
org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.7 from central in [default]
org.tukaani#xz;1.5 from central in [default]
org.xerial.snappy#snappy-java;1.1.1.3 from central in [default]
```

`spark-submit --version` output:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.2
      /_/

Branch 
Compiled by user jenkins on 2016-11-08T01:39:48Z
Revision 
Url 
Type --help for more information.
```

scala version is 2.11.8

My pyspark command:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=ipython /usr/spark-2.0.2/bin/pyspark --master spark://master:7077 --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1
```

My spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit script.py --master spark://master:7077 --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0,org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.1
```

I've read [here](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues/129) that this can be caused by "an older version of avro being used" so I tried using 1.8.1, but I keep getting the same error. Reading avro works fine. Any help?

Comment: That was a mistake of mine, `script.py` should go after the `spark-submit` parameters, but is not the cause of the error. The app is indeed being registered in the Spark Web UI. I already found the problem and a solution and will be posting it soon. Basically, Hadoop includes an avro (1.7.4) library which can get used instead of the desired one if the classpath is not set properly.

Comment: Can you please post how you solved the problem in the end? I encounter the same issue.

Comment: Just posted my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this error is that a apache avro version 1.7.4 is included in hadoop by default, and if the `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` env variable includes the hadoop common (`$HADOOP_HOME/share/common/lib/` ) before the ivy2 jars, the wrong version can get used instead of the version required by spark-avro (>=1.7.6) and installed in ivy2.

To check if this is the case, open a `spark-shell` and run

```
sc.getClass().getResource("/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.class")
```

This should tell you the location of the class like so:

```
java.net.URL = jar:file:/lib/ivy/jars/org.apache.avro_avro-1.7.6.jar!/org/apache/avro/generic/GenericData.class
```

If that class is pointing to `$HADOOP_HOME/share/common/lib/` then you must simply include your ivy2 jars *before* the hadoop common in the `SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH` env variable.

For example, in a Dockerfile

```
ENV SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH="/home/root/.ivy2/*:$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*"
```

**Note:** `/home/root/.ivy2` is the default location for ivy2 jars, you can manipulate that by setting `spark.jars.ivy` in your `spark-defaults.conf`, which is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar problem before.
Try using **--jars {path to spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar}** option in **spark-submit**